# Implementing english to other language translation in Android

Tags: android, google-translate

I am trying to translate the typed English language to any other languages.What is the better way to do it.
For example i have the example mockup for my app setup..

```
______________________________
| Textview for translated word|
| ----------------------      |
|    translated text          |
| ----------------------      |
|                             |
| Edittext to type            |
| -----------------------     |
| type text to translate      |
| -----------------------     |
|                             |
| Language selector spinner   | 
| ---------------------       |
|  Hindi             >        |
| ---------------------       |
|                             |
|                             |
|                             |
|                             |
-------------------------------
```

This design is similar to the google translate app.But i want to implement this feature in my android app.Is there any function or library to convert the text typed by the user to the language which is selected in the spinner. Or is there any api provided by google for android users to perform these kind of language translation.

For example.

```
GoogleTranslator translator = new GoogleTranslator();

someButton.setOnClickListener(new onClickListener(){

    tvDisplay.setText(translator.convertTo(etKeyboard.getText(),"hindi"));

});
```

Any help will be appreciated.Thank you.

Comment: Google translate is there, But is not enough efficient. You can start with storing static text scripts for all languages in the strings.xml.

Comment: you can try the google Translate API: https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs